# How to get first 4 items of any array or class based on their price entries in ascending order

Tags: typescript

I have a class objects given like:

```
Products: Product[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Milk', price: '1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Flour', price: '20' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Jeans', price: '29' },
    { id: 4, name: 'T-Shirts', price: '14.59' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Purse', price: '199.99' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Jacket', price: '200' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Football', price: '50' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Pens', price: '5' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Tooth Brush', price: '4' },
    { id: 10, name: 'lipistic', price: '9.89' }
];
```

In TypeScript I want to fetch the given number of items from it based on lowest prices. This number to fetch is provided on the function parameter.

```
getCheapestProduct(id:number): Product[] {
    return this.Products; // will have to return the first few elements / 
                          //(specified by id) in ascending prices.
}
```

Please help !

Comment: You can sort an array of objects by providing a callback function. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript. You have to sort the products and then get the first `n` elements. Both tasks should be solvable with a short search on SO or your preferred search provider.

Comment: @Matey how this is an array of class object not array of strings.

Comment: @yogihosting please read the provided link carefully. There is an example with sorting array of objects, it starts with "Objects can be sorted given the value of one of their properties."

Comment: thank you @Matey i am able to sort in ascending order. Now i have to take the first 4 (suppose) so how to do this part.

Comment: @Matey done now. by using slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this due to the comments given by fellow developers. Here is the solution:

```
getCheapestProduct(id:number): Product[] {
    return this.Products.sort(function (a, b) {
        return Number(a.price) - Number(b.price);
      }).slice(1,id);
}
```

First I am using the sort then using the slice.

Comment: I will be helpful if someone given the answer in terms of lambda expression too.